# How does Byte Pair Encoding work on the byte sequence?

Tags: nlp, transformer

I am reading a paper on OpenAI GPT-2, and in the paper the authors are mentioning that they have performed Byte Pair Encoding (BPE) on the byte sequence themselves, and I am not sure what they meant by that.

How is BPE on the byte sequence different from the regular BPE?

Could you give me some example?

Thank you,